# Host my WCF service as Windows service

Tags: windows, wcf, windows-services

I have WCF SERVICE PROJECT with needed BL modules.
Please, tell me, how I can deploy this project as Windows Service.
I don't undestand the MSDN sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms733069.aspx

Comment: The sample is fairly comprehensive and gives step by step instructions from beginning to end.  Which part specifically are you not understanding?

Comment: This sample describes how to create WCF service by hand, but doesn't using wcf project type. In hand implementation I have some promlems with referencing System.ServiceModel.Web

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to:

1. Create a Windows NT Service in .NET
2. Define a private member variable of type `ServiceHost`
3. Inside the service, in the `OnStart` event handler, create and open your `ServiceHost`:

   ```
   _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(YourServiceClass), new Uri("http://localhost/Services/YourService"));
   _host.Open();
   ```
4. In the service, in the `OnStop` handler, close and stop your ServiceHost.

   ```
   _host.Close();
   ```
5. Add the proper `app.config` to your NT Service

That's about all there is!

There's also a very good and very informative MSDN help page out there showing [How To Host a WCF Service in a Managed Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx)

Comment: I wanna implement REST service, for this I need to add WebGetAttribute for each web method. But I can't add reference System.ServiceModel.Web to the console or Win NT service project, wcf service library also